# How to create custom theme in Liferay with default theme as parent?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, liferay-theme

I want to figure out some things about creating and changing Liferay themes. Now I want to make few changes to default theme. I created project from maven archetype for liferay themes. Set a default theme as parent, copied all files to my /webapp folder. Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>theme</artifactId>
    <groupId>by.velcom</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>sample-theme</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>sample-theme Theme</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>theme-merge</goal>
                        <goal>build-css</goal>
                        <goal>build-thumbnail</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                <parentTheme>${liferay.theme.parent}</parentTheme>
                <pluginType>theme</pluginType>
                <themeType>${liferay.theme.type}</themeType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
        <version>${liferay.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <liferay.theme.parent>_unstyled</liferay.theme.parent>
    <liferay.theme.type>vm</liferay.theme.type>
</properties>
```

Then I changed something in styles and templates, deployed sample-theme.war.
New theme was added to Configuration->Display Settings (sample-theme). But when I choose it and apply, I don't see any changes I've made. Can someone say me what I do wrong?

Comment: This should be a good start: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/creating-liferay-themes

Answer (score 0):

If by default you mean the classic then you have to change

this

```
<liferay.theme.parent>_unstyled</liferay.theme.parent>
```

for this

```
<liferay.theme.parent>_classic</liferay.theme.parent>
```

And run the maven task so that it applies it, remember you'll have to copy only the files you want to modify.